# How do I update my component with data from my redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I've successfully integrated redux into my app. I'm fetching data from a form that sends to a database and the using an eventListener (redux-saga) the data is updated into my store.

Using Redux DevTools, I see the data in my store but my component doesn't show the data. I'm using the useSelector hook from react-redux.

My component:

```
export const DisplayUser = () => {
  const { db } = useSelector(state => state.data.db);
  var count = 0;
  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Birthday</th>
          <th>Hobby</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {db ? (
          db.map(data => {
            return (
              <tr key={count++}>
                <td>{data.fname}</td>
                <td>{data.lname}</td>
                <td>{data.email}</td>
                <td>{data.age}</td>
                <td>{data.birth}</td>
                <td>{data.hobby}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <p>Please fill the form</p>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

And here's a screenshot of my app.
[image: appshot]

Here's a screenshot of my redux store with a recently submitted input:
[image: redux-shot]

Here is the code for my reducer:

```js
import {
  SAVE_FORM,
  UPDATE_STORE
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  sent: [],
  db: ""
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_FORM:
      return {
        ...state,
        sent: [action.payload]
      };
    case UPDATE_STORE:
      return {
        db: [action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you submit is there any action being dispatched? UseSelector may not run on its own without component re-render which may be missing piece of your puzzle here. `The selector will be run whenever the function component renders. useSelector() will also subscribe to the Redux store, and run your selector whenever an action is dispatched. `

Comment: The dispatched action is what sends the form entries to the database. @Rikin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to destructure `db` from the result of your selector. You're already selecting down to the `db` key. Update your selector to:

`const db = useSelector(state => state.data.db);`

and you should be good to go.